# How to get cumulative amount total from list of Map

Tags: java, selenium

In one of my case I get the input like below which has a list inside with list of Maps.

```
List<Map<String, String>> actAllSavAccDetLists = test1Page.getAllSavingsAccountsDetails();

// returns like this

[
    {Savings=Account ****2623, Current Balance=$22000.00, Annual Rate=7.77%, Transfer=Make a Transfer, Ellipses=...}, 
    {Savings=Account ****5678, Current Balance=$11000.00, Annual Rate=2.22%, Transfer=Make a Transfer, Ellipses=...}
]
```

Now I need to find the total balance for the user, i.e.; adding up all the current balance from the Map inside a list.

Say in this case, adding $22000.00 + $11000.00 to give the result as $33000.00 in a total_bal variable.

Comment: What do you mean by `outside from a list` ?

Comment: ok, sorry if my question confuses, just ignore that. I want to get sum of all the current balance. how to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use java stream map->reduce to make that:

```java
Double totalBalance = actAllSavAccDetLists.stream()
    .map(e -> e.get("Current Balance").substring(1))
    .map(e -> new BigDecimal(e))
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But sometime it gives the result with one decimal, if it does not have fraction values. like 12.00 + 12.00 gives 24.0. How can i make it to retrieve as two decimal points even with 0's. like i need 24.00.

Comment: Just use BigDecimal rather than Double can solve the problem. I've updated the answer. @mmar

Comment: Yes, it works for my case at least. thanks much. accepted you answer.

Answer (score 1):

The java-compatible way to do it is not to have this map at all. Java is nominally typed, and really likes its types. a `Map<String, String>` is not an appropriate data type here.

1. First, make a class that represents a savings account.
2. Next, instead of having a `List<Map<String, String>>`, have a `List<SavingsAccount>`.
3. Finally, sum up the balances.

### Making a class

Looks like it would be something along the lines of:

```
@lombok.Value
public class SavingsAccount {
    String accountId;
    int balance; // in cents
    double rate; // might need to be BigDecimal
}
```

You'll need to festoon it up to become a proper java class (the fields need to be final and private, getters and setters nee dto be there, a constructor, equals, toString, etcetera). I'm using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) here (disclaimer: I'm one of the developers), but you can also use a java16 `record`, or use your IDE to generate all this stuff.

### Converting that mess into instances of SavingsAccount

Converting a map that contains for example a mapping `Transfer` = `Make a Transfer` into an instance of this rather strongly suggests your input is coming from some bizarre source. You'll know better than we do how to convert it. You can now localize all the various required conversions and open questions into a single place. For example, what should happen if, say, `map.get("CurrentBalance")` doesn't exist, or returns "€10000.00"?

This boils down to "How do I convert the string `"$22000.00"` into the integer `2200000`", or "How do I convert `"7.77%"` into a `double`", which is not difficult, and an unrelated question; if you're having trouble with it, I'm sure it's been answered a million times on SO already so you'll find it swiftly with a web search.

### Summing it up

That's trivial:

```
List<SavingsAccount> accounts = ...;
int sum = accounts.stream().mapToInt(SavingsAccount::getBalance).sum();
```

This streams all the accounts, extracts just the balance from each, and then sums the entire stream into a single number.

### I don't want to make that class

Well, it's a bit silly to do things in ways no sane java programmer would ever do. If you're trying to learn, you'll be learning the wrong ways of work. If you're trying to deliver freelance work, you'll get negative reviews. If you're "in a hurry", taking shortcuts now will just cost you triple later on. You **do** want to make that class.

If you insist on being stubborn, the same techniques can be used, just, with the order all jumbled up. You can stick the code that extracts the balance in that `mapToInt` call:

`.mapToInt(s -> extractBalanceFromThisBizarroMap(s))`

and then just write `static int extractBalanceFromThisBizarroMap(Map<String, String> s)` yourself.

But don't do that.